# Trouble configuring SSL on Apache: PEM lib error

Tags: configuration, openssl, ssl-certificate, webserver, apache2

Question:

I'm facing an issue configuring SSL on my Apache web server, and I'm struggling to identify the root cause. I've provided detailed information below, and any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Description:

I'm trying to set up SSL on my Apache web server, and I keep encountering the following error:

```
[Fri Jan 12 10:17:12.215369 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 124345:tid 140299436099456] AH02562: Failed to configure certificate [domain name] :443:0 (with chain), check [file directory for my ssl bundle]
[Fri Jan 12 10:17:12.215624 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 124345:tid 140299436099456] SSL Library Error: error:04800064:PEM routines::bad base64 decode
[Fri Jan 12 10:17:12.215631 2024] [ssl:emerg] [pid 124345:tid 140299436099456] SSL Library Error: error:0A080009:SSL routines::PEM lib
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

Key Details:

Server Environment:

- Operating System: linux
- Apache Version: Server version: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu)

File Paths and Permissions:

- SSLCertificateFile: /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl-bundle.pem
- SSLCertificateKeyFile: /etc/apache2/ssl/data-miner.key
- Permissions: Checked and confirmed www-data has read access

Configuration Snippet:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [DOMAIN]
    ServerAdmin [ADMIN]

    # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    Redirect permanent / https://[DOMAIN]/

    # ... Other HTTP-related settings ...

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName [DOMAIN]
    ServerAdmin [ADMIN]

    WSGIDaemonProcess dataMiner python-path=/var/www/dataMiner/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/dataMiner/scraperv2/website.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/dataMiner>
        WSGIProcessGroup dataMiner
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # SSL Configuration
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl-bundle.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/data-miner.key

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Additional Observations:

I've checked the certificate and key file formats, and they seem correct.
Apache error log (/var/log/apache2/error.log) provides [additional error details].

Steps Taken:

I've reviewed various online resources and attempted solutions provided.
I've verified file paths, permissions, and the order of SSL directives.
I have used openssl x509 to check it isnt corrupt and returns the bundle file without errors.
Restarted Apache after making changes.

tried everything i can find or think of at this point.

Dont think it is the certificate i was sent as it seems to be fine when i used openssl x509.

the certificates were done by digicert.

Question:

What could be causing the PEM lib error in my Apache SSL configuration?
Are there any additional steps or configurations I should check?
Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further?
I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide!